# Is there a callback for when an Angular DTOptionsBuilder ajax call finishes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, angular-datatables

I am using angular datatables and I have some code that looks like this:

```
this.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
    .withOption('ajax', {
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            ...
        },
        data: function(data) {
            ...
        }
    })
    .withDataProp('data')
    .withOption('processing', true)
    .withOption('serverSide', true);
```

That all works properly and the table on the page is populated with data when the ajax call returns. All I want to do now is detect when that ajax call completes. I have tried to use this right below `beforeSend`:

```
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR, fnCallback) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

That actually prints the returned data to the console, but when I add that `success` callback the table on the page never populates with the data. So how can I have a callback fire when the ajax is done and still have my table on the page populate with data like it normally does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dataTables is using the ajax `success` callback internally, so you break things up if you override that. However, dataTables introduces its own `dataSrc` callback which is fired from within dataTables success handler to give you the upportunity to manipulate the response before any data is inserted :

```
this.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
  .withOption('ajax', {
     dataSrc: function(json) {
       //success!
       console.log(json);
       return json
     },
     type: 'POST',
     contentType: 'application/json',
     processData: false,
     ....
```

see demo -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/94EWyDanIawCJJgyagiy?p=preview**

As you may see in the demo, you also have an alternative in the ajax `complete` callback :

```
ajax : {
  complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    console.log(jqXHR.responseText)
  } 
  ..
}
```